# Failed to locate template for civicrm.config.php

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to generate DAO and SQL files,
when I run "php ./GenCode.php" in my xml path, I get this error in my console.

```
$ php ./GenCode.php

civicrm_domain.version := 5.1.alpha1

Parsing schema description schema/Schema.xml
Extracting database information
Extracting table information

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to locate template for civicrm.config.php' in 
C:\wamp64\www\drupal\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\CodeGen\Config.php:35
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\wamp64\www\drupal\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\CodeGen\Config.php(10): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Config->setupCms()
#1 C:\wamp64\www\drupal\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\CodeGen\Main.php(115): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Config->run()
#2 C:\wamp64\www\drupal\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\CodeGen\Main.php(100): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Main->runAllTasks()
#3 C:\wamp64\www\drupal\modules\civicrm\extern\membership\xml\GenCode.php(39): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Main->main()
#4 {main}
```

thrown in C:\wamp64\www\drupal\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\CodeGen\Config.php on line 35

when I look to the config.php file, it seems correct

```
elseif ($this->config->cms !== 'joomla') {
  $configTemplate = $this->findConfigTemplate($this->config->cms);
  if ($configTemplate) {
    echo "Generating civicrm.config.php\n";
    copy($configTemplate, '../civicrm.config.php');
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception("Failed to locate template for civicrm.config.php");
  }
}
```

but it gives the same error, can you help me please? Thanks
Fidi

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today.  While this may be too late for you, what I found was that somehow, the git repo in `<webroot>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal` was set to the `master` branch and not the `7.x-master` branch.  Once I checked out `7.x-master` and did a `git pull` my problem resolved.

Comment: I totally forgot about this, but finding it saved my butt today.  Sorry I can't give you an upvote, 2019 Jon.